# Move millions of records from sql server to oracle everyday

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

I want to move millions of records from sql server to oracle in java, so the logic is,
1. select all data from sql server per the specified date range,
2. insert them into oracle one by one,
3. Delete the data in sql server

But as the data is very huge, I'm afraid the process will cost too much time. so I want to do
1. Using multiple thread to read date from sql server(Slip the specified date range to some smaller range)
2. Using multiple threads to insert date to oracle.

But I'm not sure multiple threads can solve the issue.

Wish get get some suggestions.

Comment: How much data does "millions of records" imply?  Are we talking a couple hundred MB?  Tens of GB?  How long do you have to get the data loaded?  What's the bottleneck?  Assuming that the network is the bottleneck, going directly against the SQL Server database via a database link would be much more efficient than a Java solution that would require moving all the data across the network twice.

Comment: I agree with you about Java being absolutely irrelevant in that case, but cannot agree about using SQL link for anything above 100.000 records. Dump and mass loading will be much more efficient in that case. And if dropping indices and disabling all constraints before using SQLLDR is possible, that would help also.

Answer (score 1):

1) Dump data into intermediate file (CSV or fixed-width)
2) use SQLLDR to import it

You will have to [describe](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ) your dump file for SQLLDR